# Asyncupload control of AjaxControlToolkit

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using asyncupload control of AjaxControlToolkit and I want to check the file to be uploding is already exists or
not on server.
How we can do this?
Please help me out.

```
<!-- Client side code for control-->
<script>
 function uploadError(sender, args) {
        //document.getElementById('lblStatus').innerText = args.get_fileName(), "<span style='color:red;'>" + args.get_errorMessage() + "</span>";
    }

    function StartUpload(sender, args) {                
        var nodeSelectedText = document.getElementById('<%=lblFileLocation1.ClientID%>').innerHTML;

        if (nodeSelectedText == "") {            
            $("#msgMissingSelection").dialog("open");
            args.set_cancel(true);
        }
        else {
            return true;
        }        
    }

        function UploadComplete(sender, args) {     
            var hdnFieldVal = document.getElementById('<%=hdnField.ClientID%>');

            if(hdnFieldVal.value == "1")
{
            $("#msgFileUploadExists").dialog("open");        
}
            else
            {
            $("#msgFileUpload").dialog("open");        
}
        }
</script>


<!-- Control Code in aspx-->
<tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td> 
                                <cc1:AsyncFileUpload ID="FileUpload2"  Width="265px" runat="server" 
                                    OnClientUploadError="uploadError" 
                                    OnClientUploadStarted="StartUpload"
                                    OnClientUploadComplete="UploadComplete"
                                    CompleteBackColor="Lime" UploaderStyle="Modern" 
                                    ErrorBackColor="Red" 
                                    ThrobberID="Throbber" 
                                    onuploadedcomplete="AsyncFileUpload1_UploadedComplete" 
                                    UploadingBackColor="#66CCFF" />

                                    <asp:Label ID="Throbber" runat="server" Style="display: none">
                                        <img src="../../images/indicator.gif"  align="absmiddle" alt="loading" />
                                    </asp:Label> 
                                    <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnField" runat="server" value=""/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
```

//.CS Code for ayncupload control

```
protected void AsyncFileUpload1_UploadedComplete(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AsyncFileUploadEventArgs e)
        {
string filePath="C:\Documents\temp.txt"
         if(File.Exists(filePath))
{
hdnField.value="1";//Not able to access this value
}
}
```

Thanks!!

Comment: Try this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists.aspx

Comment: Yes its right I can check file existence in AsyncFileUpload1_UploadedComplete event but also want to give message to user/client side. IS it possible to have hidden field value set in file exists loop then access it to UploadComplete of control to client side?

Comment: Can you please post your code so that we can suggest what to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just need to set your hidden field value at client side script.

See I have made little changes in your server side code:

```
protected void AsyncFileUpload1_UploadedComplete(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AsyncFileUploadEventArgs e)
    {
        string filePath = "C:\\Documents\\temp.txt";
        string hiddenValue = "0";
        if (File.Exists(filePath))
        {
            hiddenValue = "1";
        }
        //This script will set required value for hidden field.
        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "SetHiddenField", String.Format("top.$get('{0}').value = '{1}'", hdnField.ClientID, hiddenValue), true);
    }
```

**Make changes in your script location as follow:**

```
 <ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager runat="Server" EnablePartialRendering="true" ID="ScriptManager1" />

       <script>
 function uploadError(sender, args) {
        //document.getElementById('lblStatus').innerText = args.get_fileName(), "<span style='color:red;'>" + args.get_errorMessage() + "</span>";
    }

    function StartUpload(sender, args) {                
        var nodeSelectedText = document.getElementById('<%=lblFileLocation1.ClientID%>').innerHTML;

        if (nodeSelectedText == "") {            
            $("#msgMissingSelection").dialog("open");
            args.set_cancel(true);
        }
        else {
            return true;
        }        
    }

        function UploadComplete(sender, args) {     
            var hdnFieldVal = document.getElementById('<%=hdnField.ClientID%>');

            if(hdnFieldVal.value == "1")
            {
              $("#msgFileUploadExists").dialog("open");        
            }
            else
            {
              $("#msgFileUpload").dialog("open");        
            }
        }
</script>
```

Comment: It's not working.Is it because of ajax call we have for UploadComplete event and its not getting that hidden field?

Comment: I think you facing issue because the JavaScript code is not placed at proper place.your script should be after `<ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager>`, see may edited answer.

Comment: Can you please tell me , any particular reason behind adding <script> after ToolKitScriptManager?

Comment: yes after all script loaded than after the code in cs file should execute and than after the code in your JavaScript should execute.

Comment: Thanks Bhavesh its working.. Thanks a lot for your long support.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the file exists using the following:-

[File.Exists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists.aspx)

You can compare based on the filename.

Comment: Yes I am able to check the value in UploadComplete event of asyncupload control of AjaxControlToolkit but I want to give message to client that file already exists!

Comment: Have a invisible label which you can make visible to display the error text after comparing. What is the problem that you are facing there ?

Comment: Using from this link : http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/ajaxcontroltoolkitsamplesite/asyncfileupload/asyncfileupload.aspx

Comment: You can simply have an invisible label which you make visible once the file is not found inside the "uploadComplete" method in JavaScript.

Comment: Actually I am able to set or get value inside UploadComplete event.When debugging it setting value to label or hidden field but not able to get that after completion of ajax call to UploadComplete event.Please see my previous comment where I mentioned link from where I have taken code

Comment: Are you getting any JavaScript errors in the Console window of your browser after that line is executed?

Comment: Can you just post YOUR code that you are using inside "uploadComplete" function? Maybe you are not making it visible correctly or something.

Comment: Code is posted please check it.

Comment: How are you trying to access this value in your JavaScript code? Can you please post that as well ?

Comment: Made change in uploadComplete method to client side .Please check it.